# Make webpage visible if Javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, html

I have a responsive page that gets rendered again via javascript during load. But this causes a flicker because the page is rendered and then Javascript kicks in the body of page to render it again.

CSS Stylesheet and Javascript, both are contained in the html itself.

The solution I'm using now is:  in the Style sheet I set:

```
html {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

and then in Javascript at the end of onload() I call:

```
function makePageVisible(){

  document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.visibility =  "visible";
}
```

This works perfectly. But I am worried about browsers that may have Javascript disabled. I realize that it may be rare, but then I read posts where iPhones had Javascript disabled. So I'm thinking maybe its not so rare.

Anyways, is there a better way for me to hide and show the page contents that will work with and without javascript ?

Comment: Don't use JavaScript for page layout it's primary purpose is to interact with the user and the web page. CSS is designed for page layout. You might want to check out mediaqueries in CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to have a `<noscript>` tag which contains a `<style>` which makes things visible:

```
<style>
  html {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
</style>
<noscript>
  <style>
    html {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  </style>
</noscript>
```

You can also hide with Javascript instead (which won't run if JS is disabled):

```
  <script>
    document.documentElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  </script>
</head>
...
```

Comment: Thanks!
I'd already tried hiding in JS but it still caused the flicker. so that was a no go.

The <noscript> thing worked perfectly. I tested by disabling JS. I'm all set.

Comment: Are you sure you ran the Javascript to hide before the `<body>` started to load? I'd *think* that if the hiding JS runs in the `<head>`, there won't ever be anything painted on the browser until you re-visibilize it in your onload

Comment: My Script tag is at the end of body. But for testing disable in JS,  I think I did that in head, probably even before CSS.  Anyways, the <noscript> thing works perfectly so I wouldn't worry about it. Thanks again!